# How to save and append response JSON as single object in Python loop?

Tags: python, json

I have a script which calls a JSON web-service.  I can only receive 100 records per call, however, I need to write each response to an NumPy Array later in my script, how can I successfully append multiple JSON responses as a structure of a single JSON to handle this task?

Now the script below returns each response as `decoded2`.  So the first response would be `decoded2`, the second response would also be `decoded2` overwriting the 1st one.

How can I take both of these responses and make one giant JSON object?  The example JSONs below show what the upper level of `decoded2` prints as.  So I would like to append all of the LISTS OF DICTIONARIES from each output as `decoded2`.

Now the only data that writes as `decoded2` is the last dictionary where the `lastpage` parameter is 'true'.

```
while lastpage == 'false':
    r2 = requests.post(url2, data=data2, headers=headers2)
    print r2.text
    decoded2 = r2.json()
    f2 =open('C:\Users\GeoffreyWest\Desktop\Request.json')
    data2 = jsonpickle.decode((f2.read()))
    if decoded2['Response']['LastPage'] == 'false':
        data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize'] = pagesize
        startrow = startrow + data2['QueryRequest']['PageSize']
        data2['QueryRequest']['StartRowNum'] = startrow
        data2['QueryRequest']['NewQuery'] = 'false'
        data2 = jsonpickle.encode(data2)
        print startrow
    else:
        lastpage = 'true'
```

Example of output:

```
    {
        "status": {
            "code": 311,
            "message": "Service Request Successfully Queried.",
            "cause": ""
        },
        "Response": {
            "LastPage": "false",
            "NumOutputObjects": "100"
        }
    }
    #multiple json dicts within lists 


    {
        "status": {
            "code": 311,
            "message": "Service Request Successfully Queried.",
            "cause": ""
        },
        "Response": {
            "LastPage": "false",
            "NumOutputObjects": "100"
        }
    }
    #multiple json dicts within lists 




Desired Output:

{
    "status": {
        "code": 311,
        "message": "Service Request Successfully Queried.",
        "cause": ""
    },
    "Response": {
        "LastPage": "true",
        "NumOutputObjects": "76"
    }
}
#multiple json dicts within lists from JSON # 1
#multiple json dicts within lists from JSON # 2
#multiple json dicts within lists from JSON # 3
```

Comment: You don't need to use `json.loads(r.text)` when you can just do `r.json()`, which handles decoding the response to Unicode different (better) for JSON.

Comment: I have changed this within my code @MartijnPieters, but what does this have to do with my original question?

Comment: I'm giving you a quick tip in a comment, that's why it was a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Are you using `jsonpickle` for any particular reason (instead of built-in `json` library)? Can't you just accumulate results as Python data structures (append to list etc.) and convert to JSON at the end?